# Display all items in a list one by one

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items.

I want to fadeIn one item display it for 5 seconds then fade it out and then display the next item in the list. This must be continuous.

I found this code on here but it is not working for me and none of the items in the list is showing up. The items are set display none in the css

```
    function fadeLi(elem) {
        elem.delay().fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut(500, function () {
            if (elem.next().length > 0) {
                fadeLi(elem.next());
            } else {
                fadeLi(elem.siblings(':first'));
            }
        });
    }
    
    $(function() {
        jQuery('#leftList li').hide();
        fadeLi(jQuery('#leftList li:first'));
    });
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: *The items are set display none in the css* - that will likely be your issue, if it's set to `!important`.  Can you include sample html and the *relevant* css please?  See [mcve].

Comment: Your code, as provided without relevant css, works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/o1gwzy5a/

Comment: Here is the html 
```
<div>
<ul id="leftList">
 <li>
 Item 1
 </li>
 <li>
 Item 2
 </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```
Here is the CSS
```
#leftList li {
display:inline-block;
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: It's on a Wordpress site and the list is inside a html block on a widget

Comment: Thanks for providing html/css, ideally please [edit] your question to add them.  Your code still works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3q70s6wb/   Note that you have `color:white` - if your background is also white, then you won't be able to "see" the items, as in: https://jsfiddle.net/3q70s6wb/1/

Comment: The background is black that is why I made the color white. But yesterday it wasn't working at all. Today it is working. I think maybe it could have been a cache plugin or something. I did clear the cache a few times to make sure I am not dreaming. Any case thanks for your help